# How to generate random numbers under OpenWRT?

Tags: shell, openwrt

With a "normal" (I mean full) Linux distro, it works just fine:

```
sleep $(echo "$[ ($RANDOM % 10 ) ]")
```

OK, it waits for about 0-9 seconds.

but under OpenWRT [not using `bash`, but rather `ash`]:

```
$ sleep $(echo "$[ ($RANDOM % 9 ) ]")
sleep: invalid number '$['
$
```

and why:

```
$ echo "$[ ($RANDOM % 9 ) ]"
$[ ( % 9 ) ]
$
```

So does anyone have a way to generate random numbers under OpenWRT, so I can put it into the "sleep"?

Comment: ash isn't bash; you can't use bash features with it.

Comment: @user62367 someone from SO has already answer your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678836/how-to-generate-random-numbers-under-openwrt "answer").

Comment: Seriously, stop crossposting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's an (unreliable) way to produce an integer between 0 and 9 (inclusive):

```
sleep $(head -30 /dev/urandom | tr -dc "0123456789" | head -c1)
```

This reads 30 lines from `/dev/urandom`,
uses `tr` to discard all characters that aren't digits,
and then grabs only the first character of the remaining digits. 
This is unreliable insofar as there is a possibility
(with very low probability)
that `/dev/urandom` will yield 30 lines that happen to contain *no digits*.

This can be extended to generate a three-digit number (in the range 0-999)
as follows:

```
$(head -30 /dev/urandom | tr -dc "0123456789" | head -c3)
```

Comment: "This is unreliable insofar as there is a possibility …" – True. What do you need the first `head` for in the first place? Use `</dev/urandom tr -dc "0123456789" | head -c1`. If you are unfortunate then the command will take some time (it will read and discard many bytes from `/dev/urandom`). There is no upper bound for duration time, but the probability the command never finishes is 0. This means you just need to wait as much as it takes to get one digit for sure. In this sense my command is reliable. Getting more digits (like with `head -c3`) is equally reliable, it may just take more time.

Answer (score 4):

Ash doesn't understand `$[]` and it's deprecated in Bash. Also, the `echo` is unnecessary. Use this instead for both Bash and Ash:

```
sleep $(( $RANDOM % 10 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Also consider that Busybox included in OpenWrt does not usually have the `$RANDOM` compiled in.

You can have it if at compilation time you select the `BUSYBOX_CUSTOM` and `BUSYBOX_CONFIG_ASH_RANDOM_SUPPORT` configuration options in the OpenWrt buildroot.

Otherwise, you can use a command like this:

```
hexdump -n 2 -e \"%u\" /dev/urandom
```

That generates a number between 0 and 65535.
So, if you want to run sleep for 0-9 seconds you can do something like:

```
sleep $(($(hexdump -n 2 -e \"%u\" /dev/urandom) % 10))
```

where the `$((... % 10))` part is needed for reducing the 0-65535 space to 0-9.